# How to wait for elements to finish processing before getting response to console app, C#

Tags: c#, html, .net, console-application, httpwebrequest

I want to get some data from the web. Been trying to get it trough a console app using HttpWebRequest, see code below. The problem is that I get the respone too soon - It even says **Processing request...** in the response.

```
</head>
        <body style="margin:0px;" onLoad="runHourlyLister('knyc', 'icao', '2018', '1');">
                <div id="newaListerResults">Processing request ...</div>
```

I want to get the response after the processing is done.

I've tried to make a request and stream the response, aswell as delaying the task but i dont seem to get anything working. I'm pretty new with html/jquery (whatyoucallit) and need some help.

```
static private async Task MyMethod2()
        {
            HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://anyexcitingwebsite.com");
            httpRequest.Method = "GET";

            using (HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse())
            {
                string content = string.Empty;
                string documentContents = string.Empty;
                await Task.Delay(10000);
                using (Stream responseStream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    await Task.Delay(10000);
                    using (StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8))
                    {
                        await Task.Delay(10000);
                        content = await readStream.ReadToEndAsync();
                        //documentContents = readStream.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
                //Console.WriteLine(documentContents.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(content.ToString());
            }
        }
```

I expect the results something like this, but with the diving into the div classes:

```
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body style="margin:0px;" onLoad="runHourlyLister('knyc', 'icao', '2018', '1');">
    <div id="newaListerResults">
    <div id="dtable_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper no-footer">
        <div class="dataTables_scroll">
            <div class="dataTables_scrollHead" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; border: 0px; width: 100%;">...</div>
            <div class="dataTables_scrollBody" style="position: relative; overflow: auto; width: 100%; height: 530px;">...</div>
            <div class="dataTables_scrollFoot" style="overflow: hidden; border: 0px; width: 100%;">...</div>
        </div>
        ::after
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank y'all

Comment: The response you get from the server, will use javascript to get the actual result from the server. Maybe there is a (REST)Api you can use, that should be much easier, than executing some js to retrieve the actual result.

Comment: You can't, with a `WebRequest`. It downloads text. It doesn't run scripts. Use a WebBrowser control. You can subscribe to its [DocumentCompleted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted) event, verify that its `ReadyState` is [WebBrowserReadyState.Complete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowserreadystate), to determine when the page is done loading. Or use [HtmlAgilityPack](https://html-agility-pack.net/)